# marionette-forms.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: this.ui[a].addClass is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, marionette

I'm trying this [Marionette Forms library on Github](https://github.com/not-only-code/marionette-forms). Seems like some people might be using it but I'm having no luck.

I'm loading it with require.js and it seems to load.  If I create a FormView with no schema it complains properly that schema is empty so it's getting as far as parsing the view.  When I add one item to the schema the error in the post title occurs no matter what I call my form or form field.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```
        <form id="formCreate" method="post" action="http://pathtomypostaction" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <div class="row air">
                <div class="col-sm-3 text-right formlabel">Name</div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>


        var EditView = Backbone.Marionette.FormView.extend({

            el: '#formCreate',

            schema: {
                name: {
                    ui: '#form-name',
                    event: 'input',
                    type: 'text'
                }
            }    
        });     


        editView = new EditView();
        editLayoutView.getRegion('SettingsRegion').show(editView);
```

**UPDATE:** I think I might just be using this wrong.  I'm used to providing templates to Marionette views.  This thing doesn't appear to work that way.  The forms in the examples are not templates (no script tags).  I'm confused as to how this is used.  If my form is not in the DOM but in a template, can this thing handle that?

Comment: The extended `FormView` has to be PascalCase in your code: `EditView`.

Comment: Thanks.  Updated but same error.

Comment: Isaw the code in github I havent debug it but, probably you need to call this.bindUIElements() in your onRender callback of EditView

Comment: Yeah thanks.  I noticed that too.  There is a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ywjgjkxv/1/) that does it.  If I comment the bindUIElements() call it produces the same error.  But I have that call in my code now am still getting the error.  My form is in a script tag though.  It's a template.  I can't tell if that's how this is intended to be used.

Comment: I'm thinking you have to render your form first in a standard ItemView.  Then, once in the DOM, feed that html to your separate FormView.  It does say "Marionette Forms does not render your fields, you must provide the entire html form to the FormView."  I take that to mean the html can't be in a template but rather rendered in the DOM already.   Doesn't exactly fit with my work flow.